# Can I make an ESRI checkout replica from a checkout replica?

Tags: arcgis-server, esri-geodatabase, personal-geodatabase, replication

If I create a checkout from a clients geodatabase, can I then turn around and put that replica on our ArcGIS Server and create a couple replicas from it?

So, then, our replicas would be synced to the "replica" on our server which would then be exported back out to a personal geodatabase.

Would that personal geodatabase be able to be synced back to the clients database or would doing all this ruin what makes it a replica?

I hope this made sense.

Basically, what I'm trying to accomplish is getting a replica from a client that multiple people will be working on, but before syncing it back to the client, we would like the replicas we worked on synced back to 1 database so we can check the connectivity before giving it back to the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the short answer is no. You would need an sde gdb to make the second replica.
[The esri distributed database model is fully and clearly documented.](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Understanding_distributed_data/003n000000ts000000/)

[In the Esri pdf doc-

The following describes each technique:](http://downloads.esri.com/support/whitepapers/other_/ArcGISServer_DistributingData_nov2007.pdf)
  Geodatabase replication:
Geodatabase replication allows you to distribute data across two or 
more geodatabases such that edits can be made independently and synchronized periodically. It has 
built-in safeguards against data loss, data redundancy, and system instability. Geodatabase 
replication requires at least one versioned ArcSDE® geodatabase.

  DBMS replication:
ArcSDE geodatabases are built on top of DBMSs that include technology for 
replicating at the database level. Geodatabases, like other applications built on top of these 
DBMSs, can be used with this technology. Using DBMS replication with geodatabases requires 
knowledge of how geodatabase data structures are implemented at the database level. ArcGIS® does 
not provide out-of-the-box
tools for implementing these systems like it does for geodatabase replication.

  Data copying and loading tools:
Another technique for distributing data involves simply copying 
data from one geodatabase to another. This technique is useful for systems with simple 
requirements. For example, a field-worker updates a feature class and needs to copy that feature 
class to the ArcSDE geodatabase in the office each night. This technique can also be used where the 
data is nonversioned or where only personal or file geodatabases are involved. However, it has no 
built-in safeguards against data loss or data redundancy.